# Laravel 5.8 send mail via mailgun not working

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-5.8, mailgun

I am using Laravel 5.8 and i have setup my mailgun as well and verified my subdomain

I can send mail via curl but i cant send mail via the Laravel app.

**My services file**

```
'mailgun' => [
    'domain' => env('MAILGUN_DOMAIN', 'https://api.mailgun.net/v3/mg.*************.com'),
    'secret' => env('MAILGUN_SECRET', 'MY_MAILGUN_API_KEY'),
    'endpoint' => 'api.mailgun.net',
],
```

**My .env**

```
MAILGUN_SECRET=MY_MAILGUN_API_KEY
MAILGUN_DOMAIN=https://api.mailgun.net/v3/mg.*************.com
```

**My Mail file in the Mail folder**

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class VisaBooking extends Mailable
{
use Queueable, SerializesModels;

public $visa;

/**
 * Create a new message instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct($visa)
{
    $this->visa = $visa;
}

/**
 * Build the message.
 *
 * @return $this
 */
public function build()
{
    return $this->from('mailgun@mg.********.com')
    ->subject('New Visa Request')
    ->markdown('mails.visa');
}
}
```

**Controller**

```
Mail::to('joshymajebi@gmail.com')->send(new VisaBookingMail(['created_at' => $now, 'updated_at' => $now, 'destinations_country' => $destinations_country, 'residence_country' => $residence_country, 'prefix' => $prefix, 'lastname' => $lastname, 'firstname' => $firstname, 'middlename' => $middlename, 'phone_number' => $phone_number, 'email' => $email, 'departing' => $d_date, 'returning' => $r_date, 'passport_number' => $passport_number, 'passport_expiry_date' => $p_date, 'passport_issuing_authority' => $passport_issuing_authority]));
```

I dont receive the mail in inbox or spam and in my mailgun logs it does not show up.

Comment: Check your laravel logs, or your spam folder in your email

Comment: The logs are not showing anything. Like i said the spam folder contains nothing.

Comment: Can you remove the endpoint field from your mailgun setup? So keep only domain and secret. And run `php artisan optimize` just to make sure that your env values are the latest ones.